# Programmatically looking up Maven/Ivy locations to convert Ant to Ivy

Tags: maven, ivy

I'm converting an existing ant build to use ivy.  I've got names and version numbers for all our libraries, now I just need to get the maven/ivy location information for each.  I can do it by hand, but we use a lot of libraries, and I don't have time to look them all up.  Is there a program or script to look up those dependencies automatically?

Effectively, I have the jar name and the version number, and usually the artifact id. I just need to look up the group ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the following groovy script:

- https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy

In uses file checksums to discover the Maven coordinates of jars. (checksums are more reliable than file names)

Code is not perfect (Feel free to contribute a patch) but I've used it successfully introducing ivy into large legacy ANT projects.